# How to modify a firebase authentication response to include a link to the app if successfully verified?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'd like to include a link to the app so that the user was able to go straight to the login once their email has been confirmed. The firebase console doesn't show where this could be edited.

The firebase console doesn't show where this could be edited.

Pseudo-code:

Your email has been confirmed. Now please proceed to login:
Add a link to the app.

Comment: Hey @Vlad did you find a solution for the action code settings in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a continue URL via `ActionCodeSettings` to redirect the user back to the app:

```
var actionCodeSettings = {
  // After email is verified, the user will be give the ability to go back
  // to the sign-in page.
  url: 'https://www.example.com/login',
  handleCodeInApp: false
};
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendemailverification(actionCodeSettings)
  .then(function() {
    // Verification email sent.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred. Inspect error.code.
  });
```

Learn more about `ActionCodeSettings` and passing state in redirect:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions

You can also build your own custom landing page here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: This sounds like a potential solution to the issue. When trying to do it in my Flutter app, I'm unsure if it's possible though.
`/// Initiates email verification for the user.
  Future<void> sendEmailVerification() async {
    // TODO(amirh): remove this on when the invokeMethod update makes it to stable Flutter.
    // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26431
    // ignore: strong_mode_implicit_dynamic_method
    await FirebaseAuth.channel.invokeMethod(
        'sendEmailVerification', <String, String>{'app': _app.name});
  }`
No mention of actionCodeSettings...

Answer (score 0):

I think, you cannot modify the "address verified" email, if it exists. I actually only know of the "please confirm your email" mail. But, you can run a cloud function on the server to check for the verification status every so often, and then send an email with the link from there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if i understood you correctly, that'd be a strange user experience. When they click on the link in the verification email from firebase, a pop up appears that is the one I'd like to modify the text of. What you're saying is keep the pop up with the old text and build an additional layer of cloud functions which wouldn't be concurrent with the popup, but have the right text, right? Not quite what I was after...

Comment: Sorry I don't think you can modify the message. The user receives a verification email with the link to verify, he clicks on it, and a message that says something along the lines of "Your email was verified" appears. Now, what I propose, is that unbeknownst to the user, a background process is checking for this event, server side, and then the user receives another email that says "here's your download link". It's not weird.

Comment: Good point @Sergio